# why ES6 import does not work in plain js files

Tags: javascript, html, frontend, typeerror, es6-modules

I have a problem with importing into plain JavaScript files from libs
for example,currently i am trying to learn Redux and i found that i should learn redux toolkit. but when i am trying to import `configureStore` it shows me an error
importing code:

```js
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
```

error output:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@reduxjs/toolkit". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

this error occured to me first time when i tried to learn "Chart.js" but couldn't find a solution for it. that's why i decided to ask you, hoping to find the answer or the final solution to this problem.

...........................................

Comment: This: `Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"` can't be said clearer in other words than how it appears in the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers don't have access to npm or even know what it is.  So import statements like "@company/package" won't work in the browser.  You would need a build tool to grab those things out of /node_modules/ and bundle it with your app.

Alternately, you can copy the relevant parts out of node_modules itself, paste it into a folder that you know is part of your app, and import it from that location via relative path.

Comment: https://caniuse.com/?search=import